# DXA navigation based on Structure Group, how to fetch data

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

Navigation in Tridion has been created using Structure Group.Tried to fetch navigation content using `/api/navigation/{localizedId}` but returning page not found error.

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Did you publish the navigation page from the CM?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Tried publishing the page but it’s still comes with same error. Can I know the end point exposed by the content manager to fetch navigation content. Tried with below url end points: 1. /PageModel/Tom/{localizationId}/navigation.jdon 2.  /api/navigation/{localization I’d} but none  of them returning response. Can you please provide inputs

Comment: @NandaKishore: Welcome to Tridion stackexchange, please update which version of tridion sites? and ,net or java? Did you installed dxa modelservice? if yes, Is it a inprocess modelservice? Did you register modelservice endpoint to discovery-registeration? pleaes provide bit more details what exactly are you tring to do? for example exaplain bit more context about your setup example I was trying to setup sites 8.5 + DXA 2.0 OOTB somethink like that. Is there any error in your webapplication logs? please refer to this https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Velmurugan. Please find more details.We have already a tridion setup with dxa 2.0 ,SDL web 8.5. We are building an api that makes a calls to model service and able to get page content(I.e for homepage,products etc) in jdon format. We have a navigation page already created in tridion portal and able to preview in Json format. We have all this ready but not able to get navigation content. Tried with above mentioned URL formats but not able to. Can you please guide us how to make a call to the navigation page to pull the content.  Thanks again for quick response

Comment: Check the basics? Is it published? Does it show in the database? Anything else in logs?

Answer (score 1):

URLs like `/api/navigation/xyz` form the so-called *on-demand Navigation API*.

This API can only be used when the Dynamic Navigation Provider is configured. This provider uses Taxonomy-based navigation.

See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-5301172A-8A79-4F7E-B832-8510135A7EA8

Comment: Thanks for answer. DXA Model Service is configured with Dynamic Navigation Provider.  As per the documentation i tried with 1) /api/navigation/{localizationId} which is giving 404 not found and 2)api/navigation/{localization}/subtree --> List all taxonomy Id's. But my requirement is i want to get all navigation url's defined for each page within the publication. Please help me out. Besides to above query,Can you please help like what are the different ways to fetch navigation url's for the requested publication for dynamic Navigation. Can you please help out with right approach.

Comment: Please check the documentation topic for examples and explanation of the API. Your requirement sounds like you want to retrieve the entire navigation Taxonomy. This can be achieved with `descendantLevels=-1`. Also note that the DXA Model Service is *not* a public API.